# Check if web is in pagepreview mode - ?pagepreview=true

Tags: 2010, javascript, branding

How can I check if a page is in ?pagepreview=true mode?

I've branded the sharepoint ribbon and need to check if a page is in pagepreview to get the site branded correct (js / css). Is there a way to do this without checking the url with JS

```
window.loaction.href.indexOf("?pagepreview=true") > -1
```

I'm trying to check this in the ex masterpage.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a different way to check it in JavaScript, or if there is a way to check it WITHOUT using JavaScript? Where are you checking for this, within a Content Editor Web Part? Within the master page? Where?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to check this with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you can check QueryString params
*[C#]*
`bool isPagePreviewMode = Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["pagepreview"]);`